# qml works from console, but doesn't work under qt creator

Tags: linux, qt, opengl, qml, nvidia

I use

> Qt Creator 4.4.0-beta1 (4.3.82)
>
> Based on Qt 5.7.1 (GCC 5.3.0, 64 bit)

I created project based on template that provide `qt creator`: `Qt Quick Controls 2`. And do not do any modification in it.

If I press `run` button in `qt creator` I recived such message (inside console inside `qt creator`):

> Starting .../build-test1-qt5-Debug/test1...
>
> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>
> libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
>
> libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
>
> Unrecognized OpenGL version
>
> Unrecognized OpenGL version

At first, I thought about problem in linux kernel/nvidia driver/xorg and Qt cooperation, but I can run `./build-test1-qt5-Debug/test1` without any problems
from `xterm`:

> ./build-test1-qt5-Debug/test1
>
> QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
>
> qml: Button Pressed. Entered text:

So any hints what is difference between running `qml` from `qt creator`, or directly without `qt creator`?

Output of program, that I run inside `qt creator` with `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose`:

```
QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
libGL: screen 0 does not appear to be DRI2 capable
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib64/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/evgeniy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL: Can't open configuration file /home/evgeniy/.drirc: No such file or directory.
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
function is no-op
Unrecognized OpenGL version
Unrecognized OpenGL version
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same Qt library in both cases.
If you are on Linux, an idea is that in one case you are running on X11 and in the other case on wayland.

Comment: @BenjaminT Yes, I have only one Qt 5.7, and I can connect `gdb` to test application that ran "inside" qt creator, and `gdb` show the same binary libraries as if I run app inside xterm. And I have no wayland on my system, only xorg.

Comment: Do you have Nvidia card? There are [similar error messages](https://askubuntu.com/q/759647) produced by [Snaps](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/snappy) on Ubuntu on an Nvidia machine.  Following links, i got to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snap-confine/+bug/1615248).  I've heard of a similar problem with the same error messages when trying to start a [Flatpack](http://flatpak.org/) application on an Nvidia machine.

Comment: Maybe [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/snappy/+bug/1574851) is more relevant.

Comment: @Alexey Yes, I use nvidia close source driver, and corresponding hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, you have problems in projects run environment variables, you have two choices:

1. goto xterm, run env command, copy the environment variables, now goto qt creator, open run pane, in run environment select clean environment and do batch edit (via Batch Edit button) and paste the copied environment variables there, it should fix your problem
2. goto Qt Creator -> Run Pane -> Run Environment and select system environment as default run environment configuration

Comment: I doubt that issue in envrionment varibles, I tried "Clean", "System" and "Build" variants in "Project Pane" -> "Run Environment". "Clean" envrionment obviously not working, because of `DISPLAY` not setted, others cause errors that I provided in my question. Note that I run "qt creator" from the same xterm where all works as expected. Anyway I tried your advice by manually setted environment variables in "clean" configuration to output of `env`, but error doesn't change

Comment: put LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose, so the libgl will be verbose and include the verbose logs in your question.

Comment: I update my question, output of program that I run directly from xterm not changed by `LIBGL_DEBUG`

Answer (score 0):

Just got this working for myself. Try adding the following lines to your .bashrc file:

```
export LD_PRELOAD='/usr/$LIB/libstdc++.so.6'
export DISPLAY=:1
```

Refresh the terminal and run your program.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to Unset `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Projects > Run Environment. For both Kit and System Environments it was set to some value that were configured for system packages so they will depend only on Mesa and not on NVidia GLX libs.